# Reading integers from file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have a file with a numbers separated by line. I would like to scan an entire file say input.txt, and put the numbers into a vector.

I have a basic idea of how to do it but I do not know how to iterate until the end of the file.

The language is Matlab.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `textscan` or `fscanf` functions.  Both can read an entire matrix at one go.