# Read and plot .txt file (into .mat)

Tags: matlab, file-io

I need to read test.TXT file(tab delimited) into MATLAB.

TXT file have form:

```
Datum Time Data1 Data2 Data3 Data4 Data5
06/28/2012 09:27,3 1,931764 -0,008698 4,151306 33,865424 -44,923096
06/28/2012 09:27,3 1,931764 -0,003662 4,154358 33,865424 -44,831543
06/28/2012 09:27,4 1,928712 -0,001526 4,168701 33,866102 -45,472412
.....................................................
```

After that I need to plot these data (for example `time` vs. `data1`; `time` vs. `data2`..)

What is the easiest way to open and read test.txt file so I can then plot my data (insert all data to workspace..). I tried to import data, but then MATLAB import data as one column.  :/

Thanks

---

### EDIT

I just noticed that I copy wrong format of time into first post :S

```
Datum Time Data1 Data2 Data3 Data4 Data5
06/28/2012 17:09:27,3 1,931764 -0,008698 4,151306 33,865424 -44,923096
06/28/2012 17:09:27,3 1,931764 -0,003662 4,154358 33,865424 -44,831543
06/28/2012 17:09:27,4 1,928712 -0,001526 4,168701 33,866102 -45,472412
.....................................................
```

17:09:27,4  -> 17(hour), 09 (minutes), 27 (seconds), 4(miliseconds)

Here is now big problem with `,` and `.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered previously in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981038/reading-integers-from-file-in-matlab) you should use either [textscan](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) or [fscanf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fscanf.html)

After taking a closer look there are a few interesting nuances to your question.  The solution I went with was to preserve the columnar structure by reading everything as a string.  That helps to keep everything ordered while commas are replaced with periods, date strings are processed to datenums and finally the numbers stored as strings are converted.

```
fid = fopen('test.txt','rt');
header = textscan(fid,'%s %s %s %s %s %s %s',1); 
data = textscan(fid,'%s %s %s %s %s %s %s');
data = cellfun(@(x) strrep(x,',','.'),data,'UniformOutput',false);
clean_data(:,1) = arrayfun(@(x) datenum([data{1}{x} ' ' data{2}{x}]), 1:length(data{1}) )';
clean_data(:,2:6) = cell2mat(cellfun(@str2num , [data{3:end}],'UniformOutput',false));
fclose(fid);
```

There are a few messy transitions in there.  But the general approach should be solid so long as your files are not outrageously long.  Here are the results:

```
>> datestr(clean_data(:,1))
ans =
28-Jun-2012 09:27:18
28-Jun-2012 09:27:18
28-Jun-2012 09:27:24

>> clean_data(:,2:end)
ans =
1.9318   -0.0087    4.1513   33.8654  -44.9231
1.9318   -0.0037    4.1544   33.8654  -44.8315
1.9287   -0.0015    4.1687   33.8661  -45.4724
```

And finally to plot versus date, which was the original goal:

```
>> plot(clean_data(:,1),clean_data(:,2))
>> datetick
```

Comment: Yes I tried already but it's nothing working. I know I must first change all , to . and after this read line after line; Tried with this but is not OK:

fid=fopen('test.txt','rt');
while ~feof(fid)
   l=fgetl(fid) ;      
   strrep(l,',','.');   
end

Comment: I would use `fid=fopen('test.txt'); s=textscan(fid,'%s','delimiter','\n'); s=strrep(s{1},',','.');` to load and remove commas, then probably sscanf to load from there, pulling the dates out as strings then using datevec to get them into a Matlab friendly format.  I'll update my answer with a more complete solution in a second

Comment: Hmm, thanks for idea; the bigger problem is after I read data into matlab.. I hope you will found solution, i will wait; Many thanks.

Comment: thanks for this solution. But how can I now plot for example 3rd column. Plot(data(:,3), ??)    I need to plot data vs time.

Comment: Hey Alex, actually I already added a section to my answer that shows how to plot the third column in your original text file (Data1).  To plot the next column over you would use `plot(clean_data(:,1),clean_data(:,3)); datetick;`

Comment: Wow, yes it's working OK, but TIME have very strange value after plotting it "7.35*10^5" ???  Thank you again for your time and support.

Comment: The `datetick;` command **should** change the x-axis tick labels from the huge numbers (called datenums) to your choice of pretty date/time labels.  You can find its documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datetick.html).  If simply `datetick;` doesn't work you can try `datetick('x',0);`

Comment: Please look at my EDIT on post1. I didn't notice this to now :/

Comment: The code I posted still works perfectly with the new data, it substitutes . for , and transcribes correctly - what problem are you seeing?

Comment: If I use "datestr(clean_data(:,1))" then there is no miliseconds into data(:,1)

Comment: Ah, not a problem - it's there just beyond the normal precision of datestr to show.  You can get more detailed output using `datestr(clean_data(:,1),'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS:FFF');` where the FFF gives you time in milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks, but is this also included into "plot" ?

Comment: Yup, check the documentation for datetick `datetick('x','MM:SS:FFF');`